# Reading a .CSV file stored inside our C: drive inside my asp.net mvc web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, c#-4.0

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, and we have a third party system which generates a `.csv` file per hour. It will store it in the following location `c:\HRSystem\SOAPResult\Info.csv`

The file contains info about our employees such as first name, second name, telephone, hire date , etc ..

I need to read this data in my asp.net mvc code. Can anyone advice if I can read and manipulate that data inside the `Info.csv` file from within my application ?

Thanks

Comment: Try this https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/ You can find too much code just on Stackoverflow by research.

Comment: What specifically do you need help with? Accessing the file? Parsing it? Displaying the result?

Comment: @TZHX i need to read the data inside the file,,, and display it inside the view.  For example for each employee to show its first name , last name , etc... usually i read this data from a database or from json ,, but in this case the HR system we have provides a .CSV file ,,, so i want to be able to read the data from the .csv and show it inside my view ? also i need to be able to query it ,example to get the employee with first name = "my name...."

Comment: @Anirugu so there is not any built-in libraries within the .net version 4 or 4.5 ? IF not i will look into this ?thanks

Comment: @johnG  You can write your own, I am not sure but Microsoft office have some functionality for CSV (in Excel). Try to use that library and you may found something useful.

Answer (score 0):

CSV stands for comma separated values, so you should be able to add a StreamReader() to the file, and read it in row by row, splitting on a comma character.

```
...
using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\HRSystem\SOAPResult\Info.csv"))
{
    sr.ReadLine(); // if you have a header in the file
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        var columns = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
        // process columns as per needed.
    }
}
```

I'm sure that there are open-source libraries to handle CSVs as well though.